# NativeScript error - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: nativescript

I'm creating a NativeScript app and testing it on an Android emulator.  Unfortunately  I can't replicate this, but occasionally I get the error below.

The app follows simple "parent-child" template.  Going from the Parent to a Child; back to the Parent and then to a different Child - and repeating multiple times.  Each Child displays text and an image.

I'm not sure if this is unique to Android (vs iOS) or an emulator (vs physical device).

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 18925068 byte allocation with 11023464 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:831)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:739)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:615)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.image.Fetcher.scaleAndRotateBitmap(Fetcher.java:499)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.image.Fetcher.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Fetcher.java:474)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.image.Fetcher.processBitmap(Fetcher.java:263)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.image.Worker.loadImage(Worker.java:119)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.ImageView.loadImage(ImageView.java:197)
    at org.nativescript.widgets.ImageView.onAttachedToWindow(ImageView.java:58)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:14514)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2843)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4059)
    at android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.add(ViewOverlay.java:190)
    at android.view.ViewGroupOverlay.add(ViewGroupOverlay.java:63)
    at android.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:423)
    at android.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:247)
    at android.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:732)
    at android.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:405)
    at android.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1777)
    at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:306)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2055)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have you tried to determine if there is a memory leak in your NativeScript application? If not, I recommend reading this post and giving it a whirl! https://www.nativescript.org/blog/hunting-memory-leaks-with-android-studio-and-xcode

Comment: Are you doing any sort of image manipulation (download / resize / preview etc.,) in your app?

Comment: @Pixxl I'll take a look - thank you!!

Comment: @Manoj - no, no image manipulation - only displaying it given a URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `decodedWidth` / `decodedHeight` on `Image` component. Also set the `largeHeap` property on your application tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true" ....
```